# How can I import svg logo inside react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: `background: url(${require('my/path/to/svg.svg').default})`

Answer (score 0):

import .svg, .jpg, .png, .ttf, etc. files like:

```
  ReactDOM.render(
      <img src={require("./svg/exmpale.svg")}/>,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
```